# Get data from specific timestamp Database laravel-api

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, routes

i try to get data from specific timestamp into database DT.
i try this but not work
code :

```
Route::get('/l', function(){
    $day = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_GET['day']));
    $users = DB::select('select * from DT where (`timestamp` = "'.$day.'")' );

    return $users;
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

in postman i put into params : `day         2020-07-01`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

```
Route::get('/l', function(){
   
    $day = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime($_GET['day']));
    $users = DB::select('select * from DT where (`timestamp` like "'.$day.'%")' );
   
})->middleware('auth:api');
```